# vscode only show comment on line

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to right click on a line and click only show comment in vscode?

Example:

Before:

```
x = 1 # initialize x and declare 1 to it
```

After:

```
# initialize x and declare 1 to it
```

It shouldnt remove the code on the selected line/s complety, it only shouldnt show it, so the whole code i better understandable and if you finished you can click show code.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio code does not have this feature.

What I would recommend doing is writing the comments above the functions, that way if you do want to output a layman's description of your program's processes, you can run the raw txt of your program through an app that returns a textfile made up of lines beginning with '#'